# dual booting problem with ubuntu and windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows

I have installed ubuntu on computer having already windows 8 but now it is not showing windows option.Whenever I am starting my computer it is directly starting ubuntu.What should I do?
previouly I had ubuntu 13.0 I installed ubuntu 14.04 to replace.Please tell how to restore windows option again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and execute `sudo update-grub` and the output will tell you Windows partition is detected, then reboot the computer and it will appear to you again.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Ubuntu, open the terminal and run the following command :

`sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

Reboot. Windows should now appear in the boot list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to fix this problem.

Boot-Repair is a simple tool to repair frequent boot issues you may encounter in Ubuntu like when you can't boot Ubuntu after installing Windows or another Linux distribution, or when you can't boot Windows after installing Ubuntu, or when GRUB is not displayed anymore, some upgrade breaks GRUB, etc.

Boot-Repair lets you fix these issues with a simple click, which (generally reinstalls GRUB and) restores access to the operating systems you had installed before the issue.

In your Ubuntu(make sure that you're connected to Internet), open `Terminal`.

Now type these commands.(Copy > Paste > Enter line by line)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

After a while, you should see a this.

[image]

Click `Recommended repair` button. Follow the instructions(It will ask you to copy&paste some commands). You should note the URL(paste.ubuntu.com/whatever). Now reboot your computer, you should see Ubuntu, Windows 8 and other options in a purple UI. Use arrow keys to move the highlightned line and press enter. If you didn't see it, that means the repair didn't success. Paste the URL you've noted bolow.